# VB .NET SqlBulkCopy - DataTable DateTime type conversion to SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, datatable

I'm trying to use *SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer* to insert data in a certain table of an SQL database. To do so, I have a *DataTable* which is populated with records I need to save on the database. Basically my code is based on the [Microsoft's example provided for the method *SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx).

The problem is that I have two *DateTime* fields in the SQL table, and i don't know how to represent them while defining the columns of the *DataTable*. I tryed both *System.String* and *System.DateTime*, but after the code has been executed, he says he can not convert a String type to DateTime. *DataTable* columns are defined in the following way (code taken from the example linked above):

```
Dim productID As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
productID.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
```

How can i do that? What is the correct type to use for a *DataTable*'s column corresponding to an SQL *DateTime* field?

Previously, I used an SQL command to map every field, for example:

```
' Fields initialization
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Field1", SqlDbType.DateTime)
[...]
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldN", SqlDbType.NChar, 255)

' After opened the transaction
SqlCmd.Parameters("@Field1").Value = MyDateTimeSavedInAString
[...]
SqlCmd.Parameters("@FieldN").Value = "NTHVALUE"
```

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE1] The DateTime column now works, but the same kind of error is given by another column which will be saved on a *time* field in the SQL Server's table. What kind of VB .NET type i should use to map the DataTable column with the one of SQL Server marked as *time*?

[UPDATE2] I'm trying to use an SQL table with every field set to nvarchar data type, but it still gives the same error. In fact he says that it is impossible to convert the String type of the origin column in the nvarchar type of the destination column.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime - DateTime conversion works like a charm. SqlBulkCopy does not want a lot of modifications in the data - it bypasses most of SQL Server's processing for raw performance.

And you can avoid using a DataTable - it takes about an hour or two to write your own object wrapper ;) DataTables are not exactly efficient.

And try to wrap it up more- SqlBUlkCopy is terrible code in that it puts an exclusive lock on the target table. I have my own wrapper creating a temporary table, bulk copying into this and then using a simple SELECT INTO to move the data to the final table in a short atomic operation.

And be aware - below around 1000 lines it makes no sense to use SqlBulkCopy. High overhead. Rather create a long multi line insert statement.

Comment: Do you mean I should define the column with System.DateTime and use `Dim datetime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString)` to assign it something?
(I'm using SqlBulkCopy since I have to insert from 10k to at least 100k records together, for which using the classical approach with SQL transactions gives me "_red semaphore_" kind of errors).